# How to create a windows 8 like menu using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a tile like menu for my mobile application which should look like the main menu on windows 8. I am using the ionic framework version 1.0.0. Please can anyone give me pointers on how to implemeny this.

Comment: Hi.  Did any of these solutions work for you? Were any helpful?

Comment: The solution from venkat krishna was very helpful. http://gridster.net/

Answer (score 3):

**2018 Update:**

Use CSS Grid.  You can use a feature query (@supports) to provide a backup for browsers that don't support Grid currently, taking advantage instead of flexbox.  Alternatively, you could use the built-in Ionic grid and use a feature query to override the ionic styles using CSS Grid.

For example:

```
@supports (display: grid) {
  ion-content {
    display: grid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is about ionic framework. When i tried for a similar application which gives windows 8 look i used Gridster.js. have a look into it. If you find it helpful use it. [gridster](https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js)

Comment: great for gridster - didn't know about it.

Comment: Yea. It provides easy documentation also.

Comment: The above link is broken, I think now it is http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/

Answer (score 1):

you can  Use card Imaged from Ionic

```
<div class="list card">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
     <img src="avatar.jpg">
        <h2>Pretty Hate Machine</h2>
           <p>Nine Inch Nails</p>
   </div>

   <div class="item item-image">
      <img src="cover.jpg">
   </div>

   <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#">
   <i class="icon ion-music-note"></i>
   Start listening
   </a>

  </div>
```

here is the Link
[Ionic Card Images](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-images)

but Gridster is a pretty neat solution